# Assign Drupal.org bug to myself?

Tags: drupal, open-source

This is not necessarily just related to Drupal, but all open source programming. In this case, I want to work on the Drupal project.

If I want to fix a bug, is there a way to assign the bug to myself, or to state that I'm working on it? I don't want to duplicate efforts or start working on a problem, then the next day find that someone else submitted a solution. I don't want to waste my time working on something that's being addressed by someone else.

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go into an issue queue, just above the comment form you'll see a set of fields titled "Edit Issue Settings". This is a grid of options that anyone can change and the changes get tied to a comment. One of those options is "assigned", Change it from Unassigned to your Drupal.org account name. (You'll need to sign up if you haven't).

It's then polite to mention in your comment that you're taking the issue on. The getting involved guide has some good resources on how to use Drupal.org and how to interract with the community - https://drupal.org/node/317

Have fun!